# Why my Uniross Ni-Cd batteries are not getting charged?

Tags: battery

I tried charging my Uniross 1000mAh NI-Cd batteries on my Energizer Battery Charger for 5 hours (as mentioned on the charger) but it is not getting charged. I also tried charging for various other durations ranging from 6 hours to 15 hours but still it is not getting charged.

I also tried charging these batteries on Camelion Battery Charger for 9 hours (as mentioned on the charger) but it is not getting charged.I also tried charging for various other durations ranging from 10 hours to 12 hours but still it is not getting charged.

Are the batteries damaged or there is some problem with the charges?

Comment: When you say the batteries are 'not getting charged', do you mean:
'After charging the batteries are still completely dead and have no charge at all'
or
'After charging the batteries are slightly charged, but I get much less use out of them than I would consider reasonable.'

Comment: How old are the batteries? its most likely they have had it. get a new set and try them!

Comment: Yes, Henderson. The batteries are completely dead and have no charge at all.

Comment: Thanks Darkcat Studios for your answer. The batteries are just 3 years old and not much used since purchased.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't recharge your  Ni-Cd battery for a long period of time than your battery voltage becomes 0 and it will never be recharged again.

You can follow the steps to check your battery,

Charge your not working battery for 5-6 hours with working charger and try to measure output voltage with voltmeter. You can go to near by electronic repair shop also if you don't have voltmeter.

If the measurement is zero than your battery is dead.

Before disposing your battery you can try "zapping" to make it work again. Zapping is a process which you involves a little bit of electronics knowledge. You can find about zapping on the web.

If you want to dispose than dispose it in some kind of e-waste garbage dump.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer. I found the related video on YouTube.